# How do I append the result of a PowerQuery to itself?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Let's say I have a table as follows

```
| make      | model     | license | mileage | book value |
|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|------------|
| ford      | F150      | 123456  | 34000   | 35000      |
| chevrolet | Silverado | 555778  | 32000   | 29000      |
|           |           |         |         |            |
```

Let's pretend I had to unpivot and all that, which I've done. I just used simplified data for this question. Now let's assume I run the query today (July 30th) I want my result to be:

```
| Date       | make      | model     | license | mileage | book value |
|------------|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|------------|
| 2020-07-30 | ford      | F150      | 123456  | 34000   | 35000      |
| 2020-07-30 | chevrolet | Silverado | 555778  | 32000   | 29000      |
|            |           |           |         |         |            |
```

I want to add the day the query is run. However, here's where I am stuck. Let's say I ran the query tomorrow, I want it to add the new values to the bottom of the existing result:

```
| Date       | make      | model     | license | mileage | book value |
|------------|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|------------|
| 2020-07-30 | ford      | F150      | 123456  | 34000   | 35000      |
| 2020-07-30 | chevrolet | Silverado | 555778  | 32000   | 29000      |
| 2020-07-31 | ford      | F150      | 123456  | 34200   | 35000      |
| 2020-07-31 | chevrolet | Silverado | 555778  | 32156   | 29000      |
```

This would allow me to track the fleet over time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/02/09/how-to-create-a-load-history-or-load-log-in-power-query-or-power-bi/